# OOP Design to Avoid Object Another Object in Two Ways

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a Java chess game and am trying to sort out the design.  Here's what I have so far for classes:

Game: consists of 2 player objects and a board object

Player:

Board: consists of a 2d array (8 x 8) of Square objects, each of which may / may not have a piece on it

King, Queen, Rook, Bishop, Knight, Pawn:

Piece: superclass of the above pieces, shared functionality goes here

Here's what I don't like: I have a field called "board" within my Square class, so that I can reference the board a given square belongs to.  I don't like this design because it leads to issues with cloning down the line.

So I want to rewrite some functionality in the piece class without doing this sort of backtracking.  It's great for a board to be able to access each of its squares, but I don't want to have a getBoard() function for the Square class.

Here's an example of a function that I need to rewrite:

```
public Square getSquareOneMoveAway(Square start, int heightChange, int widthChange) {

    Square candidateSquare = start.getBoard().getNearbySquare(start, heightChange, widthChange);

    if (candidateSquare != null) {
        if (candidateSquare.isEmpty()) {
            return candidateSquare;
        } else if (! candidateSquare.getPiece().getColor().equals(start.getPiece().getColor())) {
            return candidateSquare;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that in my Player class, I have methods such as:

canMovePiece(Square start, Square end, Board board), movePiece(Square start, Square end, Board board), etc.

Should I move this method into the Board class and that way I'll have access to the board object without having to go from the Square to the board?

Any ideas much appreciated,
bclayman

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Code Review, although the Code Review people will yell at me for saying so. A "board" is just that, a board. It doesn't know what's being played on it. A *chess* board might... or you might have a class that has a board and knows what moves are able to be made based on a piece's move capabilities, or the rules might be encapsulated elsewhere since there are variations of chess that alter those capabilities. There are a *lot* of options.

Comment: @DaveNewton We only yell when you vote to close for that reason, and for recommending a blatantly CR-off-topic post to CR. Thank you for still having the courage to recommend CR!

Comment: I think you could use a full review of your code. Include all the code of the relevant classes and let the people of [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) do their magic! (assuming you have *implemented* your design and that it *works as intended*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you're over-engineering the problem. Is there really any advantage of representing the squares of the board with yet another class? If not (and I don't think so) I'd just get rid of the **Square** class.

```
class Board {
    public static final int MAX_ROWS = 8;
    public static final int MAX_COLS = 8;

    private Piece[][] squares;

    public Board() {
        squares = new Piece[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ];
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'd have a **Position** class, though, holding a pair of a row and a column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you then just have a board be an array of pieces, many of which are null (representing empty)?

Comment: Yep. The board is fixed, and not very big, so, why not? Unless you're programming in an embedded system, with severe constraints of memory, you can afford an array of (8x8=)64 positions. No big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The following definition of `ChessBoard` is used to store the pieces, store they're positions, and use that information to determine if a given move is valid.

```
class ChessBoard implements Board {
    Piece[][] pieces; // null if vacant at that position

    @Override
    public boolean isValidMove(Player player, Square start, Square end) {
        Piece pieceStart = pieces[start.row][start.col];
        Piece pieceEnd = pieces[end.row][end.col];

        return (
            pieceStart != null &&
            pieceStart.getColor() == player.getColor() &&
            pieceStart.isValidTransition(start, end) &&
            (pieceEnd == null || pieceStart.canDefeat(pieceEnd))
        );
    }
}
```

Note that the logic for whether a move is valid is encapsulated in the piece that is being moved.

```
class Pawn implements Piece {

    @Override
    public boolean isValidTransition(Square start, Square end) {
        int dH = end.col - start.col;
        int dW = end.row - start.row;
        // return if is valid transition for a pawn in terms of dH and dW
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canDefeat(Piece otherPiece) { 
        return (
            this.getColor() != otherPiece.getColor() &&
            this.getStrength() > otherPiece.getStrength()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getStrength() { ... }

    @Override
    public Color getColor() { ... }
}
```

The square class is just a simple 2-tuple that contains the row and column.

```
class Square {
    int row, col;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pragmatist, so I wouldn't have pieces as classes, just enums. So:

```
enum Pieces 
{
   Pawn,
   Rook,
   Knight
   // etc
};
```

Then I'd create an interface called 'Rule' like so:

```
interface Rule
{
   void addRule(Pieces p);
};
```

Therein, by having a class implement the rule I can decide on how units interact in the game (or preferably on it). This class would be PawnRule, QueenRule etc. In doing so, it will be possible to add as many rules as possible to the game and utilising them. This not only favours extensibility but brings a viable foundation to the game itself.

```
class PawnRule implements Rule
{
    private boolean pFirstMove = true;
    // etc
    void addRule(Pieces p)
    {
        if (Square.hasSpace(Space.FRONT) * 2 && pFirstMove)
        {
            // where renderer holds 2D/3D data pertaining to the piece
            rendrerer.getModel("Pawn").moveByTwo(); // somehow
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to design, there's a lot more to take into account; and it may be that enums aren't what you're looking for. We also don't know whether the game is text-based, 2D or 3D. Generally, it's easier to implement this stuff if it's text-based but more sophisticated when it's 3D. I recommend drawing up a Class Diagram and even a Communications Diagram so you know how classes/enums/interfaces in your chess game interact with one another.